# Java code is not letting me call a method from one class to another

Tags: java, class, methods

Hey guys sorry this is a pretty long question but I cannot call printPASSInfo() to another class using pm.printPASSInfo().  pm is the name I named the class that the method I am trying to call is in.  I can call the method pm.printSSNInfo just fine I do not understand what is going wrong.  I am sorry this is probably confusing and very long but please try to help.  Thanks guys! Heres my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Prog1Methods_FA11 {
    String ssn, pw, phoneNumber,line;
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    boolean validPW_Length = true, 
            validPW_Symbols = true, 
            validPW_enough_Digits = true;
    boolean validSSN_Digits = true, 
            validSSN_Format = true, 
            validSSN_Length = true;
    boolean validPhone_Symbols = true, 
            validPhone_Format = true, 
            validPhone_Length = true;

    public Prog1Methods_FA11() {

    }


    // you may insert a method here to display password status
    public void printPASSInfo(){
        System.out.println("\t Password Information");
        System.out.println("The Password:\t" + pw);
        System.out.println("Password Lrngth:\t" + validPW_Length);
        System.out.println("Password has minimum number of digits:\t" + validPW_enough_Digits);
        System.out.println("Password has correct symbols:\t" + validPW_Symbols);
    }

    // you may insert a method here to display the phone number status

}
```

and here is where I am trying to call it:

```
case 2:     System.out.println("Enter a password witha atleast 8 characters and atleast 2 numbers:\t");
                        pw = input.nextLine();
                        pm.readAndVerifyPASS(pw);
                        pm.printPASSInfo();
                        break;
```

and the comile error:

```
MySkeletonProgram1_FA11.java:53: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method printPASSInfo()
location: class Prog1Methods_FA11
                            pm.printPASSInfo();
                                                          ^
1 error
```

Where I declare pm object:

```
public class MySkeletonProgram1_FA11{
  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

// Declarations

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
Prog1Methods_FA11 pm = new Prog1Methods_FA11();
```

Comment: Show us the statement / context where you try to call that method.  Show us the compiler error.

Comment: And in the future, you can omit extraneous code that does not affect the question at hand (like extra prints, empty methods, unused variables, etc). Sometimes you will even be able to isolate and solve your own problem this way.

Comment: ive been staring at this for an hour and havent found anything which is why i thought that there was some random thing I'm being retarded about...

Comment: EDITED to show where I am trying to call it.

Comment: Most of your code is irrelevant to the question. Remove all code not *directly* relevant to the question to provide a [SSCCE: Short Self-Contained Correct Example](http://pscode.org/sscce.html)

Comment: @Josh: you're still not showing any error information as was requested in the first comment?!

Comment: EDITED AGAIN now shorter and with compile error...sorry

Comment: @Josh: edited your question adding code tags for the error message and deleting the obnoxious "Anyone?" line at the top of your question. If you want our help, please let's cut out the melodramatics. Also posted  an answer below.

Comment: Edited with declaration of pm

Comment: @Josh: then you need to create and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: NO. Have you read the link many of us have given you??

Comment: The link has been posted on this page by two of us, a total of three times. Please read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how well I understood your question.
I just tried to reproduce the error.
So, what I've done.
1. File MySkeletonProgram1_FA11.java

```
public class MySkeletonProgram1_FA11 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Prog1Methods_FA11 pm = new Prog1Methods_FA11();
    pm.printPASSInfo();
}
}
```

2. File Prog1Methods_FA11.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prog1Methods_FA11 {

String ssn, pw, phoneNumber, line;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean validPW_Length = true,
        validPW_Symbols = true,
        validPW_enough_Digits = true;
boolean validSSN_Digits = true,
        validSSN_Format = true,
        validSSN_Length = true;
boolean validPhone_Symbols = true,
        validPhone_Format = true,
        validPhone_Length = true;

public Prog1Methods_FA11() {
}

// you may insert a method here to display password status
public void printPASSInfo() {
    System.out.println("\t Password Information");
    System.out.println("The Password:\t" + pw);
    System.out.println("Password Lrngth:\t" + validPW_Length);
    System.out.println("Password has minimum number of digits:\t" + validPW_enough_Digits);
    System.out.println("Password has correct symbols:\t" + validPW_Symbols);
}
}
```

3. I've put both files in the same directory.
4. Compilation command

```
javac MySkeletonProgram1_FA11.java
```

Compilation finished successfully without errors and warnings.

Does it work for you? If the answer is "No", then I think it's a problem with your JDK. Otherwise you might want to provide additional details. What are you doing differently?

Comment: Yea the entire program is acting this way.  I will have to wipe it and start completely over... :(  Thank you everyone for your patience and help!!

Answer (score 0):

With the class you pasted, this compiles and runs fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Prog1Methods_FA11 pm = new Prog1Methods_FA11();
    String pw = "foo";
    pm.readAndVerifyPASS(pw);
    pm.printPASSInfo();
}
```

Try it, and post any errors you get.

Comment: Keep getting this message:    MySkeletonProgram1_FA11.java:53: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method printPASSInfo()
location: class Prog1Methods_FA11
       pm.printPASSInfo();
                                                          ^
1 error

Comment: If you can instantiate it but not call the method, then it sounds like you might need to recompile Prog1Methods_FA11.java

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. The error message may be due to uncompiled code. Try to re-compile/Build and run.

Comment: I suggest you to create a small HelloWorld program in your IDE. If your HelloWorld program runs without any error, your program should run properly.